# Where can I redirect to a different page in React-router 1.0

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
render(){
    if (!this.readyForStep()){
        this.props.history.pushState(null, `step2`);
    }
    // Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.
}
```

So I can't redirect in render()... where in a component lifecycle can/should I?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the specific semantics you want redirecting before or after `render`, you can make this check in any of `componentDidMount`, `componentWillReceiveProps`, or `componentDidUpdate`.

Synchronous transitions lead to state updates in the `<Router>` component, so you can't make them in any place where you normally couldn't call `setState`.